# How to set default paper size to A5

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

I want to set my prnter's default paper size = A5

My code is

> printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = 11;

but this code does not work. Is there any other way? Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just blindly modify one property within the `PaperSize` object and expect it will work. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `PaperSize` property reads:

> Set the PaperSize property for the page to a valid [PaperSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), available through the [PrinterSettings.PaperSizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.papersizes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection.

If the printer supports A5 paper size, you can check the [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize.kind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for a [`PaperKind.A5`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.paperkind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value to lookup the correct settings. Or, make yourself a custom `PaperKind` instance with the respective dimensions.